# Username and navbar in angular

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

How to show username after login in angular but I can't
because iam new in angular
[code1][1]
[code2][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnit2.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yB25.jpg

token-guard.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(public userService: UserService, public router: Router) { }
    canActivate(): boolean {
        if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.router.navigate(['service-lang']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UserService {

  MAIN_LINK: string = 'https://link';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  login(user: any) {
    return this.http.post<{ token: string }>(this.MAIN_LINK, user);
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    const helper = new JwtHelperService();
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    // const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(token);
    // const expirationDate = helper.getTokenExpirationDate(token);

    const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(token);

    if (!token)
      return false;

    if (isExpired)
      return false

    return true
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
  logoutUser(){
     localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

user.model.ts:

````
    email: string;
    gender: string;
    password: string;
    name: string;
}```
````

Comment: Can you add the code here?

Comment: Once you trigger the login function, return the user info from the api and set it in your UserService inside a function. and then use the UserService anywhere to get the user information.